# find a person who has worked at least in these technologies[reactjs, mysql, express] from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contain name and technologies field.

```
-----------------------------
|name       | technologies  |
-----------------------------
|shashin    | reactjs       |
-----------------------------
|shashin    | mysql         |
-----------------------------
|krupali    | express       |
-----------------------------
|paras      | mysql         |
-----------------------------
|shashin    | express       |
-----------------------------
|paras      | php           |
-----------------------------
|krupali    | php           |
-----------------------------
|shashin    | php           |
-----------------------------
```

I want to find a person name who has worked at least in all these technologies[reactjs, mysql, express].

**OUTPUT:**

```
-------------
|name       |
-------------
|shashin    |
-------------
```

Comment: Questions that look for server-specific solutions tend to fair better

Comment: What is the bounty raised for ? I believe that the accepted answer is already sufficient enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try like following.

```
select name from TableName
group by name
having count(distinct technologies) > 2
```

if you want in specific technologies, you can try like following.

```
 select name from TableName
 where technologies in('reactjs', 'mysql', 'express')
 group by name
 having count(distinct technologies) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine, but I prefer

```
  SELECT name 
    FROM table_name
   WHERE technologies IN ('reactjs', 'mysql', 'express')
GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT technologies) = 3
```

The `DISTINCT` ensures that you will have **exactly 3** records for each name if and only if they match all three technologies. Any other technologies will be removed by the `WHERE`

In fact, if you put a unique composite index on `(name, technology)` on the original table, and only allow each technology to appear once for a given name, you can drop the `DISTINCT technologies` from the query above

```
  SELECT name 
    FROM table_name
   WHERE technologies IN ('reactjs', 'mysql', 'express')
GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

---

**As a side note**, I'd be very tempted to separate out my people and technologies into separate tables, and join them together with a third table

- person - `id`, `name`, …
- technology - `id`, `name`, …
- person_technology - `id`, `person_id`, `technology_id`

With `person_id` and `technology_id` being foreign keys to the respective tables, and unique indexes on

- technology - `name`
- person_technology - `(person_id, technology_id)`

Then your query would become

```
  SELECT p.id,
         p.name AS person, 
         t.name AS technology

    FROM person p

    JOIN person_technology pt
      ON pt.person_id = p.id

    JOIN technology t
      ON t.id = pt.technology_id
     AND t.name IN ('reactjs', 'mysql', 'express')

GROUP BY p.id, p.name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```